# Graph of Firebase user property

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

My iOS app adds a user property “nbrOfAddedExercises” for each app user.
This is an integer number.

How can I plot a graph that shows the distribution of this? Looking “for number of users vs nbrOffAddedExercises” graph.

I searched the firebase analytics interface but there seems to be no option like this? Probably possible with bigquery but kindof hopening I would not need it....